# As kafka publisher how can I differentiate consumer groups for different set of data for the same topic?

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, spring-kafka

I have a Kafka publisher which sends data to a topic and two consumer groups consuming data from the topic. I want to send some common data for both the consumers groups to consume but some data specific to individual consumer groups. Can this be achieved ? If yes, how?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you would need to use two separate topics for that kind of scenario.

Or, you could send all to both and filter out the unneeded records for one of the consumers.

See [Filtering Records](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/current/reference/html/#filtering-messages) (if your consumers are Spring consumers).

Comment: Thanks Gary for the suggestion. Actually, all the data that I send to my topic for my consumers are the same except one field which I want only a specific consumer to receive. This field will have sensitive data as the value which I don't want my other consumers to receive. Any further suggestions, please?